# Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter Not Working With Multiple Conditions for Host Not Equal

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

When my URL is localhost:8080, the rule below for Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter wrongly always results in localhost:8080 redirecting to www.example.com.

That behaviour for seems contrary to Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter reference manual!

What I want is for localhost:8080 to remain unchanged without redirection, to allow testing on local computer.

I wish to avoid unwanted URLs which are NOT at the example.com domain from being indexed by search engines.  The unwanted URLs have a different domain but point to the same/duplicate example.com pages.

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Avoid wrong hostname's pages being indexed by search engines</name>

        <condition name="host" operator="notequal" next="and">www.example.com</condition>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal" next="and">localhost:8080</condition>

        <from>^/(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://www.example.com/$1</to>
    </rule>
```

**Alternative:**

I also tried it another way: removing all condition elements, and altering "from" to be:

```
   <from>^/(^www.example.com|^localhost:8080)(\?.*)?$</from>
```

i.e. not equal to example.com and not equal to localhost -- but that has same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you do but couldn't find a solution using tuckey. I end up solving this compatibility of localhost-test and domain-name-consistency by using the interceptor in Spring. My code is like this

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
if (!url.startsWith("http://localhost") && !url.startsWith("http://www.example.com")){
    response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com"+request.getRequestURI());
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

but there will be the necessary overhead to check in every request. Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked for me.  I preferred a permanent redirect instead of the temporary redirect offered by response.sendRedirect(...).  Therefore I made the body of the if statement as:

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com"+request.getRequestURI());
    return false;

Answer (score 0):

as you are using regex match-type please try giving to the condition a regex too. E.g. `<condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.example.com$</condition>`

Comment: Thanks. I'm no longer working on that project, so won't be able to try out your suggestion.  (I was on the understanding that in Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter, name="host" is a complete hostname such as www.example.com or example.com so regex (typically for URLs) shouldn't be needed?  However, I don't know for sure; your suggestion is worth a try by someone else.)